# C++ problem in declaring a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am unable to see what is wrong in the following (very contrived) code. It might be the way I have declared a size 2 vector inside the `mystruct`. But isn't that how we declare a vector of size 2 whose contents we have yet to initialize?

```
struct mystruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  vector<double> c(2);    };

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mystruct test;
  (test.c)[0]=3.4;
  (test.c)[1]=1.8;
  return 0;    }
```

The compiler is throwing me the following error message:

g++ -Wall simple.cpp

simple.cpp:18: error: expected identifier before numeric constant

simple.cpp:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

simple.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

simple.cpp:32: error: invalid types ‘[int]’ for array 
subscript

simple.cpp:33: error: invalid types ‘[int]’ for array subscript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot initialize `mystruct::c` in the class definition, this has to be done in the constructor.

```
struct mystruct {
  mystruct() : c(2) { }
  vector<double> c;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to *construct* `c` in your `struct` declaration. Vectors only have a size upon construction. Try:

```
struct mystruct {
    mystruct(): c(2) {}
    int a;
    int b;
    vector<double> c;
};
```

The `mystruct()` constructor uses the member initialisation syntax `c(2)` to construct `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a constructor if you want to initialize the vector (call vector's constructor)

```
struct mystruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  vector<double> c;

  mystruct():
    c(2)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just not how C++ works.

When you declare a class, you *cannot* specify constructors for member objects (with the exception of static constant integrals). Instead, you must specify the constructor arguments for members in the class's constructor initializer list:

```
class Foo
{
  std::vector<int> v;
public:
  Foo() : v(2) { }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid declaration:

```
vector<double> c(2);
```

You probably want:

```
vector<double> c;
```

Then, in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     mystruct test;
     test.c.push_back(3.4);
     test.c.push_back(1.8);
     return 0;
}
```